# PHP how to echo the first value of each group in a mysql query list

Tags: php, mysql

To better explain my situation, please take a look at this mokeup query result:

```
Category    Item
cat1        Item 1
cat1        Item 2
cat1        Item 3
cat23       Item x
cat23       Item y
cat23       Item z
X           apples
X           oranges
X           bananas
and so on....
```

I am pulling the data off a mysql database and **would like to display the results like this**:

```
Category----Item
cat1        Item 1
            Item 2
            Item 3
cat23       Item x
            Item y
            Item z
X           apples
            oranges
            bananas
and so on....
```

I tried different ways but I am coming up empty. This is the latest attempt:

**PHP**

```
//Headers
echo 'Category';
echo ' | ';
echo 'Item';
echo "\n";

$sql = "SELECT `table1`.*, `table2`.* FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON `table1`.`Category` = `table2`.`Category` ORDER BY `table1`.`Category`, `table2`.`Item`";
$dbq = mysql_query( $sql );
$cat = '';
while( $data = mysql_fetch_assoc( $dbq ) ) {
    if( !$cat == $data['category'] ) {
        $cat = $data['category'];

        echo $cat;
        echo ' | ';
        echo $data['item'];
        echo "\n";
    }
    else {
        echo '     ';
        echo ' | ';
        echo $data['item'];
        echo "\n";
    }
}
```

With this code, the current output is:

```
Category----Item
cat1        Item 1
            Item 2
            Item 3
            Item x
            Item y
            Item z
            apples
            oranges
            bananas
```

...rather than the desired output.

I am looking for the most efficient and simple way to echo each category 1 time only. Perhaps this code is not the best way to approach it, but I tried in different ways and my brain right now is shut S_S .

Comment: what is in $sql variable ....i mean which query you using

Comment: @NullPointer I edited my question to include the query.

Comment: @NullPointer By the way, the query works fine. My problem is the php code

Comment: @Omar Your updated code should work; And I think that's the most efficient way in a small CLI program. What did you get from it?

Comment: This is starting to seem more like an issue with the query or database than with the PHP.

Comment: @richardhsu As I mentioned before, the query works just fine. It gives me what I need. My problem was the php code to output the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me quite some time...

Change

```php
if( !$cat == $data['category'] ) {
```

To

```php
if( $cat != $data['category'] ) {
```

Comment: By the way, is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: @Omar In my opinion, this is the best way (in the context of not-large CLI program). It uses the smallest cache (only one `$cat`), and it's fastest (compare to those who cache results before output).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're looking for as that solution seems like it solves what you need it to do but if you want to be more tolerant of the result orders you can try this:

```
$concated_data = array();
while( $data = mysql_fetch_assoc( $dbq ) ) 
{
  if ( ! array_key_exists( $data['category'], $concated_data ) )
    $concated_data[$data['category']] = array();

  array_push($concated_data[$data['category']], $data['item']);
}

foreach ($concated_data as $category => $items) 
{
  echo $category;
  $count = count($items);
  for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
  {
    if ($i == 0)
      echo "\t";
    else
      echo "\t\t";

    echo $items[$i]."\n"; // Items
  }
}
```

Formatting up to you at this point I guess but I think putting the data into an array of arrays is the best way so the top level keys are categories and then the arrays they point to now hold an array of your items. This also doesn't assume that you get results in the same category consecutively.

Sorry code might contain bugs as I haven't coded in PHP in awhile. But basically you should accumulate the items first then go through the accumulated list and output the data.

Comment: it seems that it solves itself, however, if you try it, only echoes the first record.

Comment: I updated the inner for loop to be based on index. Not sure if that'd make a difference to your comment that it only echoes the first record. I'll keep thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Better to concatenate the Items of same category and store it like as Item1,Item2,Item3.

When you want to use this Items use explode() to split and

when ever you want to search in this items for a particular item use mysql's [FIND-IN-SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: I am not sure I am following you...?

Comment: sure, this idea works for me, for your convenience  better to estimate the future difficulties with this method once...

Comment: I am even more confused >_< Could you please elaborate with your answer?

Comment: @Omar i am saying that at the time storing data in table2 you have to store the rows as ### cat1 -->  Item1,Item2,Item3   #####      cat23 --> Item X, Item Y, Item Z ....     so when you retrieving data  from table2 it will gives you the result as you need..